# C# - Determine if Method ReturnType is of a specific Type

Tags: c#

I have a class named `PathInfo`. Several of the methods in my project return a `Task<PathInfo>`.

I'm getting the methods in my project via reflection. I need to see if a method returns a `Task<PathInfo>`. My question is, how do I do that?

At this time, I have a `MethodInfo` instance. I noticed that the `MethodInfo` instance has a property named `ReturnType`. However, I don't know how to use that property to determine if the `ReturnType` is a `Task<PathInfo>`.  Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried? The obvious thing to me without actually checking in detail would be something like `ReturnType==typeof(Task<PathInfo>)` ...

Comment: it is a bit too obvious.  I suspect the missing detail is that he doesn't have PathInfo either.

Comment: @HansPassant: That may well be the case but if so they have given no indication that this is unknown or where it would otherwise come from. That having been said I've demonstrated in my answer what to do if you have a `Type` object (which is much the same). If they don't have an object with the type in either though then we can only guess at how they need to work out the match criteria...

Comment: Have you walked through this step-by-step in a debugger?  I find when I write reflection code I spend a lot of time stepping through my code and looking at the values of all the variables, their properties, etc.  If you post some code (especially dummied up, simple code that illustrates your problem (for example having "class PathInfo { }"), we'd be better able to help.

Answer (score 2):

`ReturnType` will return a `Type` object. You should be able to simply compare this to your type to see if they match:

```
var isOfType = methodInfo.ReturnType == typeof(Task<PathInfo>);
```

if the type you are comparing to varies then as long as you have it as a type object you can do much the same with a variable of type `Type`:

```
Type myType = typeof(Task<PathInfo>); // Assignment as an example - this type could easily come from a method parameter or elsewhere
var isOfType = methodInfo.ReturnType == myType;
```

Comment: To add, you can use a known method which returns `Task<PathInfo>` to capture the type in the `Type` variable in case you can't (or for some reason don't want to) use `typeof(Task<PathInfo>)`